# Class Trip, how many groups

Tags: combinatorics

Question

A group of 12 children and 4 adults are camping. There are 5 tents that will have 3 children and 1 adult how many groupings are there?

I came across a similar question where I got it wrong due to over counting and I feel I will make the same mistake again by grouping the children and adults together as distinguishable items. So I attempted

$$\frac{12!}{(4!)^4}$$ .... which is wrong

Edit:

After multiple follow-ups about the $5$th tent, this is what I found out.

The problem is correct in stating $5$ tents

$1$ adult and $3$ children go into a tent.

we don't have to really consider it.

So I'm guessing it is just there to do a job of being confusing.

With this new info is it correct to solve in this way.

$$\frac{12!}{(3!)^4} = 369,600$$

Comment: Did you mean 4 tents?

Comment: How did you get $\frac{12!}{(4!)^4}$?

Comment: It's because of the faith tent, it's been messing with the way I think of this problem. And yes the problem specifically states 5 tents. I figure the extra tent would be added to the groups. I realize that was very wrong to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "faith tent"?

Comment: 5 tents cannot all have 3 children and 1 adult, because that would imply there are 15 children and 5 adults. Did you mean to say 4 tents perhaps?

Comment: I suppose that by "faith tent", you mean *fifth* tent ? Is it supposed to remain empty or are some partially filled tents allowed ?

Comment: I asked about the 5th tent in regards to the problem and was told the problem is correct. I followed up by asking about the empty tent and was told that a tent will have 3 children, 1 adult. For my 3rd follow up I was told that the tent does not have to be considered.